# Jquery: Como mostrar cada valor de um radio button em div's separadas quando clicado?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um comparador de produtos onde, como exemplo, devo selecionar apenas dois produtos dentro de um universo com 4 produtos.

No caso o usuário selecionaria dois produtos dentro desse universo com 4 produtos e logo abaixo desse universo de produtos apareceriam informações dos dois produtos selecionados posicionadas uma do lado da outra (coluna 1 e coluna 2).

Para isso, estou codificando com Jquery, ajax e php para que quando for identificado a seleção de dois produtos, o ajax busque as informações desses mesmos no banco de dados (até aqui tudo bem).

A minha dúvida é: Como faço para que seja possível eu selecionar apenas dois produtos utilizando radio button limitando sempre apenas a duas seleções? E além disso, como faço para que a informação do produto selecionado apareça na coluna 1 e o segundo produto selecionado apareça na coluna 2?

Abaixo segue o que tenho desenvolvido até o momento:

**Estrutura html que mostra 4 produtos com seus respectivos radio buttons:**

```html
<h2 class="mb-3">Produtos</h2>
  
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  
<div class="col-2">

<img src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/h_840,f_auto,q_auto,fl_lossy,c_fill,g_auto/cde9362a09ba4dd38c9ead6600ac074e_9366/Tenis_Duramo_SL_2.0_Preto_GW8336_01_standard.jpg" width="100px"/>

<input class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="produto1" id="1" value="Tênis preto">
<label class="form-check-label" for="1"></label>

</div>

<div class="col-2">

<img src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/h_840,f_auto,q_auto,fl_lossy,c_fill,g_auto/7ed0855435194229a525aad6009a0497_9366/Tenis_Superstar_Branco_EG4958_01_standard.jpg" width="100px"/>
    
<input class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="produto2" id="2" value="Tênis branco">
<label class="form-check-label" for="2"></label>
  
</div>

<div class="col-2">

<img src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/h_840,f_auto,q_auto,fl_lossy,c_fill,g_auto/9326e8db8d8e4e509e42ad26010cf693_9366/Tenis_adidas_4DFWD_Pulse_Preto_Q46451_01_standard.jpg" width="100px"/>
    
<input class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="produto3" id="3" value="Tênis verde">
<label class="form-check-label" for="3"></label>

</div>

<div class="col-2">

<img src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/h_840,f_auto,q_auto,fl_lossy,c_fill,g_auto/7a80a0e74201457eb1e5adcb00ff92f8_9366/Tenis_Dropset_Trainer_Azul_GZ2941_01_standard.jpg" width="100px"/>
    
<input class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="produto4" id="4" value="Tênis azul">
<label class="form-check-label" for="4"></label>

</div>

</div>

<div id="coluna1"></div>
<div id="coluna2"></div>
```

Abaixo, o código jquery que pega os valores dos itens selecionados e demonstram essas informações em suas respectivas colunas, onde não é permitido selecionar mais que dois produtos:

```js
$('.radio').change(function(){
    
    var calcado = $(this).val();
    var count = $("input[type='radio']:checked").length;
    
    if(count > 2){
        
    alert("voce não pode comparar mais que dois produtos");
      
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    
    return false;
      
    }
  
  // como faço para que se possa sempre selecionar apenas dois produtos mostrando informações dos produtos selecionados separadamente?

    $('#coluna1').text(calcado);
    $('#coluna2').text(calcado);
    
    // 

});
```

No caso, como eu poderia melhorar o meu código para chegar no resultado descrito? Como exemplo prático fiz um esboço no JSFidle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhreywzu/

Comment: Veja na documentação [`<input type="radio">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) que está tentando utilizando o componente para a finalidade errada, radior buttons são projetados para selecionar apenas um valor de um conjunto.

Comment: Fiz uma postagem no stackoverflow global sobre este mesmo problema e os gringos foram super gentis. Dê uma olhada por lá e perceba como me deram uma solução sem negativar minha dúvida. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519894/jquery-limit-user-to-select-only-two-radio-options-at-once-and-display-values-i

Comment: Você vem falar de gentileza e me acusa de votar negativo na sua pergunta só porque fiz um comentário? Não senhor, olhe aqui https://imgur.com/a/MaStE0t você tem três voto negativos e um positivo, se eu tivesse negativado ficaria assim  https://imgur.com/3FgcBMi quatro votos negativos e um positivo.

Comment: Relaxa. Ficar assim é pior. Se ver meu comentário eu agradeci teu feedback. Aprenda ser gentil ;)

Comment: Você me acusa do que eu não fiz e me manda relaxar. Não sou seu familiar e nem seu amigo, se não tem provas de má conduta minha não me acuse. E não vou dar um negativo apenas porque me  deixou com ódio pessoal seu.

Comment: Que Deus ilumine teu caminho com muita luz. Fique com ELE \_/

Answer (score -3):

Encontrei uma solução para essa questão. No caso utilizei um checkbox ao invés de um radio button. Abaixo segue o código Javascript que pega os valores do checkbox e os disponibiliza em uma div conforme o usuário vai clicando nas opções:

Na parte do html as duas divs que mostram os valores dos checkbox selecionado, foi acrescido uma class "output" conforme abaixo:

```html
<div class="output" id="coluna1"></div>
<div class="output" id="coluna2"></div>
```

E abaixo, o código que pega os valores do checkbox e inseri os mesmos nas divs id coluna1 e coluna 2:

```js
let $output = $('.output');

let updateSelections = () => {

  $output.text('');

  $calcados.filter(':checked').each((i, el) => {

    $output.eq(i).text(el.value);

  });
}

let $calcados = $('.radio').change(function() {

  if ($calcados.filter(':checked').length > 2) {

    $(this).prop('checked', false);

  } else {

    updateSelections();

  }

});
```

Fonte da resolução do problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519894/jquery-limit-user-to-select-only-two-radio-options-at-once-and-display-values-i